# Does a C# (.NET 4.5) application appear in the Windows' Task Manager?

Tags: c#

Do C# console applications appear in the task manager?

I'm trying to get it both to appear, and the Publisher and Process Name columns to be what I expect.

In my AssemblyInfo.cs I have done this:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Test Title")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("Test Desc")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Test Company")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Test Product")]
```

But while my console app is running (ran from command line as the current user) I don't see any of these values in the Task Manager's Processes or Details tabs (Windows 10).

I know if I create a WinForms project I can get the columns to populate as I expect in Task Manager.

Edit:
My goal is to see all processes whose binary was created by my company. The "Details" tab of Task Manager shows the application filename (without extension) as the Description, and has no tab for Company/Publisher (right clicking on the header and choosing "Select Columns" doesn't have a publisher option.

The "Processes" tab does show the expected publisher, but it has no available Description column and if the program is run from the command prompt you need to first expand the correct Windows Command Processor record in Task Manager.

Comment: Console applications will show as a "Console window host" (conhost.exe) process rather than under its assembly name

Comment: @ivanPfeff: It shows up as a separate process with its executable name in the Details tab of Task Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

In the Processes tab, the AssemblyTitle text definitely appears.  Although it will be on a child branch beneath your "Windows Command Processor" console process, and you'll have to expand it to see your application within.

In the details tab, you can get the AssemblyDescription to appear as well.

The publisher is not shown by default but if you right-click on the headers and enable that field, it will be shown as well.

If you right click the process and choose properties, you'll see the AssemblyProduct text as well.

Answer (score 1):

Below is my Console Application running from the command line. So Yes, they do show up in Task Manager.

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Stack Overflow")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("FooBar")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("StackOverflow Test")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © fooBar  2018")]
```

[image: Screenshot]

The Properties of the Process:

[image: Properties]

Comment: It's not quite the same in Windows 10. Under the Process tab, for example, I don't see the entry for my binary until I expand "Windows Command Processor"